# In "Gone Girl", is there a significance to Amy's repeated head injuries?

Tags: analysis, gone-girl

In "Gone Girl", it seems as though the are a lot of injuries to Amy's head: the male criminal who steals her money knocks her head against a wall, she conks herself with a hammer, and probably others I've forgotten. They were unsettling and I suspect it's because of the way director David Fincher foreshadowed them or the context he put them in. Is there any significance / symbolism to the repeated head injuries?

Comment: Appart from the fact that she is not right in the head?

Answer (score -1):

She hit herself in the face with the hammer as part of her disguise. Her black eye supported the story she gave to her neighbor at the motel.

Comment: This in no way answers OPs question, stated in the title and in the question body.

Comment: Yes it does. I give the "significance" of the "conk ... with a hammer".

Comment: OP is looking for the director's message.  This is what is meant by significance.  You merely described causes.